# When the error reappears error handling does not work

Tags: ms-access, vba

Logics:

- User. Presses the button;
- Code . Creates a "Recordset" "rstStud" (students) and "rstGroupStud" (Student Groups);
- Code . Cycle. Enumerates "rstStud";

  - Code . Add entry to "rstGroupStud";
  - Code . If the record exists, go to the next record in the loop;
  - Code . If the entry is new, add an entry in "rstGroupStud";
    Essence: one click of a button - add one unique entry.

**Problem.**
When the cycle passes! StudentName = "Student Name 2" in the line ".Update" I get an error.
**Error:**
*"Failed to make changes due to duplicate values ​​in
index, primary key or relationships. Change the data in one
or multiple fields containing duplicate values
delete the index or override it by allowing
duplicate values ​​and try again. "*

In other words, the first time the error handler works normally, and when I re-fire, I get an error.

**Question.**
How to make the code work according to the described logic?

```
Private Sub btnAddRecord_Click()
    Dim nameStud As String

    Dim rstStud As DAO.Recordset   '
    Dim rstGroupStud As DAO.Recordset '

    Set rstStud = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_02_Students", dbOpenSnapshot)  '
    Set rstGroupStud = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_03_GruopsStudents", dbOpenDynaset)  '

    ' *** rstStud
    With rstStud
        Do Until .EOF = True
            nameStud = !nameStud

            On Error GoTo errend
            ' *** rstGroupStud
            With rstGroupStud
                .AddNew

                !idGroup = Me.id_GroupFrm
                !nameStud = nameStud
                ' nameStud
                .Update
            End With
            rstGroupStud.Close
            Me.frm_03_GruopsStudents_tbl.Requery

            Exit Sub
errend:
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    rstStud.Close
    Set rstStud = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Update_1**
File - [link](https://dropmefiles.com/MeVCE)

Comment: From the top screenshot, it looks like you have a field named "PrimaryKey", but it's the only one that isn't part of the composite primary key.

Comment: @Comintern Excuse me.
I do not understand what needs to be done to solve my problem?
Could you formulate more precisely what to do?
Thank.

Comment: Move your error-handling code out of the "happy path" - make it a completely separate label that only ever runs in an error state. The problem you're having is that when an error occurs you're not `Resume`-ing, so the next loop iteration is still running in an error state and then any subsequent error can't be handled.

Comment: Without seeing a dependencies diagram, it looks like the idGroup and NameStud fields are forming a composite primary key instead of both of them being foreign keys to their respective tables.  That's a M-M joining table, correct? The point being that you shouldn't approach this from the standpoint of how to "fix" the error handling - you fix it by not attempting to write duplicate keys.

Comment: FYI nobody in their right minds is going to download a macro-enabled file from a random stranger on the Internet - that dropbox link isn't useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to de-tangle the execution paths; normal and error execution states are intertwined, that's why any error beyond the first one can't be handled.

```
Private Sub btnAddRecord_Click()
    Dim nameStud As String

    Dim rstStud As DAO.Recordset   '
    Dim rstGroupStud As DAO.Recordset '

    Set rstStud = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_02_Students", dbOpenSnapshot)  '
    Set rstGroupStud = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_03_GruopsStudents", dbOpenDynaset)  '

    ' *** rstStud
    With rstStud
        Do Until .EOF = True
            On Error GoTo ErrHandler
            nameStud = !nameStud

            ' *** rstGroupStud
            With rstGroupStud
                .AddNew

                !idGroup = Me.id_GroupFrm
                !nameStud = nameStud
                ' nameStud
                .Update
            End With
            rstGroupStud.Close
            Me.frm_03_GruopsStudents_tbl.Requery

            Exit Do
TryNext:
            On Error Resume Next
            .MoveNext
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Do
            On Error GoTo 0
        Loop
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    rstStud.Close
    Set rstStud = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Resume TryNext
End Sub
```

That way `ErrHandler` only ever runs in an error state; `TryNext` runs in the "happy path", and `Exit Do` breaks out of the loop (but not out of the procedure) so that the cleanup code can run whatever the outcome is.

Answer (score 1):

You must call `Err.Clear` to reset the error state

```
errend:
    Err.Clear
    .MoveNext
```

I would call `Me.frm_03_GruopsStudents_tbl.Requery` after the loop. There is not point in requerying the form all the time.

But jumping to another regular code part instead of going to an error handler is not the usual way of handling errors. To address the possibility to handle errors on `MoveNext`, change the code like this:

```
Private Sub btnAddRecord_Click()
    Dim nameStud As String

    Dim rstStud As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rstGroupStud As DAO.Recordset

    Set rstStud = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_02_Students", dbOpenSnapshot)
    Set rstGroupStud = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_03_GruopsStudents", dbOpenDynaset)

    ' *** rstStud
    With rstStud
        Do Until .EOF = True
            nameStud = !nameStud

            On Error GoTo UpdateError
            ' *** rstGroupStud
            With rstGroupStud
                .AddNew

                !idGroup = Me.id_GroupFrm
                !nameStud = nameStud
                ' nameStud
                .Update
            End With
            rstGroupStud.Close
            Me.frm_03_GruopsStudents_tbl.Requery

            Exit Sub
continue_loop:
            On Error GoTo MoveNextError
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With

CleanUp:
    On Error Resume Next
    rstStud.Close
    Set rstStud = Nothing
    Exit Sub

UpdateError:
    Resume continue_loop

MoveNextError:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume CleanUp
End Sub
```

This pattern is extensible. You can add as many error handlers as required.

Comment: I never encountered this case. But then you would have to implement two different error handlers.Put a `On Error Goto someOtherPlace` before `.MoveNext`.  You cannot continue anyway in this case and would have to leave the `Sub`

Comment: @Comintern: I updated my answer with a better structured error handling.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it in VBA. Do it in a query instead.

For example, you could do this way:

Create a query named `qryAssignStudentsToGroup`:

```
PARAMETERS id_GroupFrm INT;
INSERT INTO tbl_03_GruopsStudents (idGroup, nameStud)
SELECT id_GroupFrm, nameStud
FROM tbl_02_Students AS s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT NULL
  FROM tbl_03_GruopsStudents AS g
  WHERE s.nameStud = g.nameStud
    AND g.idGroup = id_GroupFrm
);
```

Then your code behind becomes:

```
Private Sub btnAddRecord_Click()
  With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryAssignStudentsToGroup")
    .Parameters("id_GroupFrm") = Me.id_GroupFrm
    .Execute
  End With
  Me.frm_03_GruopsStudents_tbl.Requery
End Sub
```

This gives you much less code for same thing, and you eliminate the complexity around error handling simply by filtering out the rows. More importantly, you perform a bulk update *once*, rather than for each row you touch. This leverages the power of database engine. It's convenient to do things in a loop with a DAO.Recordset but that's row-by-agonizing-row programming. You really want to get in mindset of set-based programming.